# How can I pull the official images of IBM Container Service?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

Environment
cf version 6.12.2-24abed3-2015-07-15T21:21:22+00:00
Docker version 1.8.0, build 0d03096

I followed the steps here([CLI Setup](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html)) and setup Cloud Foundry CLI, Cloud Foudnary IBM Containers plugin and Docker.

I can login Bluemix.

```
cf login
API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net
Email> abc@def.com
Password> 
Authenticating...
OK
```

And I can get the information of bluemix official images.

```
cf ic images
REPOSITORY                           TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmliberty   latest              2209a9732f35        2 weeks ago         263.6 MB
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode      latest              8f962f6afc9a        2 weeks ago         178.9 MB
```

When I tried to pull the image, it requests authentication.I entered my ID/Password, it returned error.

```
docker pull registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode

Username: abc@def.com
Password: 
Email: abc@def.com
Error response from daemon: Wrong login/password, please try again
```

What does this authentication need?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a lost password, not about programming.  You may be able to get help from IBM Cloud Foundry's website (look for "forgot password?" or "register" near a login form) or by contacting them directly.

Comment: Sorry I skip the details. I can login by [cf login] command using "abc@def.com/mypassword". So, I can get infomation of images "cf ic images". I don't think my password is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login using the `cf ic login` or `ice login` command as shown on http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html

Logging in the Bluemix Cloud Foundry and Bluemix Containers is separate.

Comment: Thanks,Driss. Sorry, I overlooked it.

Comment: Good to hear you found it.